# Timer running every time in the loop

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How can I get the timer to run again whenever the value of i increases?

this is my code:

```
     while (i < tekrarsayisi){

     await setTimeout(function(){
     message.channel.send("message");
     }, 10000);

     i++
 
     }
```

The timer in my code works once.
how can i get this to work when it back to top ?

Comment: The timer's working for me `tekrarsayisi` times, having `i` initialised with 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot await `setTimeout()` directly, try this

```
while (i < tekrarsayisi){

    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10000));
    message.channel.send("message");

    i++

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use setInterval? I have prepared an example for you.

```
await setInterval(function() {
    message.channel.send("message");
}, 10000);
```

Or you can use a setInterval that works until it reaches the selected number.

```js
let repeat = 0;

let repeater = setInterval(function() {
    if (repeat < 3) {
      console.log('message');
      repeat++;
    } else {
      clearInterval(repeater);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: @ScrayXxX I'm sorry it didn't work for you. You should learn how the functions you use work.

Stackoverflow and its volunteers do not provide ready-made answers. It offers solutions to your problem or allows you to look from different points. Please learn about community culture.